# horizontalArrangement not working in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have tried applying SpaceBetween, SpaceEvenly and SpaceAround but nothing seems to be working here. My main goal here is to put the iconButton and the text on the start and end of the same row. Please don't refer to me appbar for doing so I just want to know why this is not working and what is the fix?

[image]

```
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(30.dp),
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween
        ){

            Text(
                "NOTES",
                fontSize = 30.sp,
                fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                color = Color.White
            )

            IconButton(onClick = { /*TODO*/ }) {
                Icon(
                    Icons.Filled.Search,
                    contentDescription = "Search",
                    tint = Color.LightGray
                )

            }

        }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add the modifier `fillMaxWidth()` in your `Row`

```
Row(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween
){
   //....your content
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In the Row modifier use `fillMaxWidth()`

```
Row(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .padding(30.dp),
    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween
)
```